# Which is the right way to create primary key column in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

As the title says, I have:

```
CREATE TABLE Status
(
    StatusId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    StatusName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    DateCreated DATETIME NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT DF_Status_DateCreated DEFAULT (GETDATE()),

    CONSTRAINT PK_Status 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (StatusId)
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE status 
( 
     statusid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     statusname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
     datecreated DATETIME NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT df_status_datecreated DEFAULT (GETDATE()) 
)
```

The first example is the same as the last? What are the differences?

I get that the first example specifies that the `StatusId` is an identity column and that the value of the first record will be 1, and that the value for each subsequent record will increment by 1

But beside that are there any other differences?

Comment: The difference is that you can either name your constraint or let it take on an automated name. I much prefer to name them so they are easy to find and identify later.

Comment: @SeanLange I see, thank you for your time

Comment: Note that you also have `IDENTITY(1,1)` in the first example, but not the second example.  Also an important difference.